# Warning: Calling `sha256 "digest" with Brew on macOS

Tags: macos, terminal, homebrew

Since the last time that I ran the `brew update` command in my macOS, I started to have this issue below. Running `brew style --fix` doesn't solve it.

How could I solve it?

[image: macOS brew error sha256]

```
Warning: Calling `sha256 "digest" => :tag` in a bottle block is deprecated! Use `brew style --fix` on the formula to update the style or use `sha256 tag: "digest"` instead.
Please report this issue to the henkrehorst/bc tap (not Homebrew/brew or Homebrew/core), or even better, submit a PR to fix it:
  /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/henkrehorst/homebrew-bc/Formula/apr-util-bc.rb:10

Warning: Calling `sha256 "digest" => :tag` in a bottle block is deprecated! Use `brew style --fix` on the formula to update the style or use `sha256 tag: "digest"` instead.
Please report this issue to the henkrehorst/bc tap (not Homebrew/brew or Homebrew/core), or even better, submit a PR to fix it:
  /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/henkrehorst/homebrew-bc/Formula/apr-util-bc.rb:11

Warning: Calling `sha256 "digest" => :tag` in a bottle block is deprecated! Use `brew style --fix` on the formula to update the style or use `sha256 tag: "digest"` instead.
Please report this issue to the henkrehorst/bc tap (not Homebrew/brew or Homebrew/core), or even better, submit a PR to fix it:
  /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/henkrehorst/homebrew-bc/Formula/apr-util-bc.rb:12

Warning: Calling `sha256 "digest" => :tag` in a bottle block is deprecated! Use `brew style --fix` on the formula to update the style or use `sha256 tag: "digest"` instead.
Please report this issue to the henkrehorst/bc tap (not Homebrew/brew or Homebrew/core), or even better, submit a PR to fix it:
  /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/henkrehorst/homebrew-bc/Formula/openssl-bc.rb:15

Warning: Calling `sha256 "digest" => :tag` in a bottle block is deprecated! Use `brew style --fix` on the formula to update the style or use `sha256 tag: "digest"` instead.
Please report this issue to the henkrehorst/bc tap (not Homebrew/brew or Homebrew/core), or even better, submit a PR to fix it:
  /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/henkrehorst/homebrew-bc/Formula/openssl-bc.rb:16

Warning: Calling `sha256 "digest" => :tag` in a bottle block is deprecated! Use `brew style --fix` on the formula to update the style or use `sha256 tag: "digest"` instead.
Please report this issue to the henkrehorst/bc tap (not Homebrew/brew or Homebrew/core), or even better, submit a PR to fix it:
  /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/henkrehorst/homebrew-bc/Formula/openssl-bc.rb:17
```

Comment: Did you get a solution for this, I'm also facing the same 

```
Warning: Calling `sha256 "digest" => :tag` in a bottle block is deprecated! Use `brew style --fix` on the formula to update the style or use `sha256 tag: "digest"` instead.
Please report this issue to the homebrew/core tap (not Homebrew/brew or Homebrew/core), or even better, submit a PR to fix it:
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to specify the path of your Formula to fix it, try to run this command below.

```
brew style --fix /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/henkrehorst/homebrew-bc/Formula
```

example

```
$ brew style --fix /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/pnbv/homebrew-ffmpegvidstab/ffmpeg.rb
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
Using ...
Fetching ...
Installing ...
Bundle complete! 31 Gemfile dependencies, 84 gems now installed.
Bundled gems are installed into `../../usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle`
Removing ...
 /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/pnbv/homebrew-ffmpegvidstab/ffmpeg.rb:9:5: C: [Corrected] sha256 should use new syntax
    sha256 "468153bac4b90b445fa5c6adfb70ec3213ebc0f63c7a97a6b2a1649d9c32a786" => :mojave
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
...
1 file inspected, 21 offenses detected, 21 offenses corrected
```

Answer (score 0):

It works on my macbookpro!!!

```
brew style --fix /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/henkrehorst/homebrew-bc/Formula
```

But,fix it need some times,just wait...

Answer (score 0):

this is the command that correct my issue:

```
brew update-reset
```